# VBA IE click on Button on Javascript page

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I would need help with automating webpage. On login page there is sign in button but I did not find way how to click on it.

html code

```
<INPUT onclick="return isFirstClick()" class=button type=submit value="Sign In">
```

using below did not worked

```
IE.document.getElementsByClassName("button")(0).Click
```

I was also trying to loop through elements with no luck.

thank you.

Comment: Try this `IE.document.querySelector("INPUT[value='Sign In']").Click`. Make sure to see if the `INPUT` is in block letters.

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: Sorry I can not. @SIM I am getting error 438 (obj not support this prop. or method)

Comment: @QHarr the website is intranet website it would not work outside...also I dont know if this can help its JD Edwards system

Comment: Ok. No worries. Thanks for responding.

Comment: That means your browser doesn't support `querySelector()`. Which version of IE you are using @Filip Ondo.

Comment: @SIM I am using IE11 version 11.2125.14393.0

Comment: That should support `.querySelector()`. Strange!!!! Now give this a shot: `Dim HTML As HTMLDocument: Set HTML = IE.document: HTML.querySelector("INPUT[value='Sign In']").Click
` Create newline removing colon `:`

Comment: wow that worked!! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this button is the first one on the website?

You can check it by adding

```
Dim HTMLButtons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Set HTMLButtons = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("button")

debug.print HTMLButtons.length 'print how many buttons are in the html code

For Each HTMLButton In HTMLButtons
    'printing some info about each button on the website
     Debug.Print HTMLButton.className, HTMLButton.tagName, HTMLButton.ID, 
            HTMLButton.innerText
 Next HTMLButton
```

Comment: I am getting error even on Set HTMLButtons = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("button") not sure whit since button should be class name

Comment: actualy there could be another button on the webpage hidden. `code` <INPUT id=jdeowpBackButtonProtect type=hidden value=PROTECTED name=jdeowpBackButtonProtect>`code`

Comment: So, instead of getElementsByClassName("button"), try to get collection of INPUTs: Set HTMLButtons = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("INPUT") or check the solution proposed by SIM above.

Comment: thanks, I will try that. Solutinon from SIM is not working for me :(

Comment: Could you provide URL of the website you want log into?

Comment: website is intranet website it would not work outside...also I dont know if this can help its JD Edwards system